# Inserting highscore record into SQLite database, nullpointer - Android (java)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have trimmed the code to try and include only the snippets needed.  I am making a trivia game and when the game completes, Results.java shows and displays the stats from the current game and sends the completed game to the highscores (SQLite Database).  When the Results.java class is called it gives a nullpointer exception (I commented in where the NP results).

This is my first time ever trying to make and implement a SQLite Database into one of my projects.  Any other advice on code structure or something else that looks wrong with my database code is much appreciated!

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

    //variables

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) { 
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
        myDB = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();
        if(dbExist) {
            //Do nothing - DB already exists.
        } else {
            myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ("
                            + RANK + " INTEGER,"
                            + SCORE + " LONG,"
                            + PERCENTAGE + " INTEGER"
                            + ");");
        }
    }

    //Insert new record.
    public long insert(int rank, long score, int percentage) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(RANK, rank);
        values.put(SCORE, score);
        values.put(PERCENTAGE, percentage);

        return myDB.insert(DB_NAME, null, values);  //Line 56
    }

                //other methods...

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
}
```

Results.java

```
public class Results extends Activity {

    DatabaseHelper dh;

    int rank;
    long score;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    //...
                    dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
                    score = getIntent().getLongExtra("score", -1);

                    //...
    }

    public void showResults() {

        //...

        percentage = 10 * cAnswers;

                          //...

        dh.insert(1, score, percentage);  //Line 100
    }

    public void restart() {
        //...
    }
}
```

EDIT:  NullPointer error is gone but a new LogCat output is displaying which can be found below.

LogCat output

```
12-18 19:47:48.280: E/SQLiteLog(1527): (1) no such table: highscoresDatabase
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527): Error inserting percentageX=30 scoreX=827 rankX=1
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: highscoresDatabase (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO highscoresDatabase(percentageX,scoreX,rankX) VALUES (?,?,?)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at com.example.test.DatabaseHelper.insert(DatabaseHelper.java:56)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at com.example.test.Results.showResults(Results.java:100)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at com.example.test.Results.onCreate(Results.java:50)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-18 19:47:48.370: E/SQLiteDatabase(1527):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't put

```
DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

in the field declaration space. this is because you don't have access to `this` the context 'till at least `onCreate` or the other Activity methods. try moving the lines that refer to `this` to inside `onCreate`.

Comment: delete all instantiation references of `dh` and refer all its methods to `db`. this is to deal with only one adapter object in the activity. but as aforementioned it was being instantiated incorrectly.

Comment: Yea my bad, I was trying to edit Eclipse and this forum without copying and pasting and screwed it up bad.  There never should have been a "db".  I edited my OP.

Comment: the `onCreate` method of your database helper is empty.. and we can't know if you've ever called `createDatabase()` to create the tables. the way it's normally done is you simply put your `.execSQL` in `onCreate`. it already checks whether it exists or not. Furthermore it does not need to be called, it is called automatically when it's needed. try modifying your database in this way or trying to view your database contents.

Comment: Those were useful comments that I did not know about the 'onCreate' method.  I will scrap the 'createDatabase' method and just stick the '.execSQL' in the 'onCreate'.  I will dabble with it some more and see what I can do.  Thank you again.

Comment: be sure to look at @Sam's *addition* response as well. it's certainly a possibility that i didn't catch and nonetheless could be the root dilemma.

Answer (score 4):

You can only use your Activity's Context after `onCreate()` is called, otherwise it isn't valid yet. Simply change your code to this:

```
DatabaseHelper db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

---

**Addition**

```
no such table: highscoresDatabase
```

You are using the wrong String, use `TABLE` instead of `DB_NAME` on line 56:

```
return myDB.insert(TABLE, null, values); // Line 56
```

Comment: Why do you think `dh` should be any different from `db`? Also you probably only once database adapter not two.

Comment: Oh dang, I edited wrong and posted the wrong LogCat on the edit.  I knew that wasn't right.  I'll fix my OP.

Comment: You were using the database's name in `insert()`'s table name parameter, I updated my answer